# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Issue occurs in jdk 17
Issue not reproduced in jdk 11

Below are maven dependencies

io.cucumber - cucumber-java - 6.10.0 , io.cucumber - cucumber-jvm-deps - 1.0.6 io.cucumber - cucumber-cucumber-junit - 6.10.0

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter

```
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:807)

    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)

    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)

    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:50)

    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)

    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)

    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)

    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)

    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)

    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)

    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)

    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)

    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)

    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)

    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)

    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)

    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)

    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)

    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)

    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)

    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)

    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)

    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)

    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)

    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)

    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)

    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:55)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:137)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:107)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:83)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:75)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:158)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)

    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)

    at ?.Given Launch the ContainerLINK Application on "UWP-USB"(About.feature:98)
```

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje it doesn't answer my question

Comment: The exceptions you are seeing are not possible with the version of Cucumber you listed. You should follow the tutorial. https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Issue is not occurred with jdk 11

Comment: Issue observed with jdk 17

Comment: I removed XStream from Cucucmber in version 3. Follow the tutorial.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Any resolution so that it works with jdk 17???

Comment: Start from scratch. Follow the tutorial. Learn about Maven.

Comment: Configured maven as in tutorial 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:678)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @59e5ddf